# Calculate variance in R

Tags: r, variance

```
   unique.identifier zip.code household profession gender age value1   value2 value3 coupon
1               197386 47508827         4        low female  24  35.13    82.50   0.00      1
2               197386 47508827         4        low female  24  36.01    72.98   0.00      1
3               197386 47508827         4        low female  24  35.87    82.13   0.00      1
4               197386 47508827         4        low female  24  38.87    76.62   0.00      1
5               197386 47508827         4        low female  24  41.89     0.00   0.00      1
6               197388 17557326         2        low      m  38  26.81     0.00  29.98      1
7               197388 17557326         2        low      m  38  25.61     0.00   0.00      1
10              197392 22830028         2        low      m  33  25.66     0.00  19.99      1
```

im trying to caculate variance value1,value2,value3 according to unique identifier
like variance of `35.13 82.5 36.01 72.89 35.87 82.13 38.87 76.62 41.89` as they share the same unique.identifier

what code should i use?

Comment: Please indicate what you tried so far, which resource/documentation you already searched, ... So that helpers can better understand your problem and give you the right answer.

Comment: Not sure why the question is downvoted, seems rather clearly formulated.

Comment: @Maxim.K Are you being ironic? Normally I expect a question of this quality to be downvoted into oblivion. I don't see any effort by OP.

Comment: @Roland I'll agree it's not the best :) But I've seen worse, and this one is well-formulated, with a reproducible example, and is on-topic with the SO scope and rules. I believe the ultimate goal of this site is to help, and we as helpers should not be too snobbish about the level of questions. Sometimes people do not know even where to begin, and if it is easy to help, we should just help. But hey, that's just my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `by`:

```
by(dat[c("value1", "value2", "value3")], dat$unique.identifier, FUN= sapply, var)


dat$unique.identifier: 197386
    value1     value2     value3 
   7.90708 1250.04828    0.00000 
----------------------------------------------------------- 
dat$unique.identifier: 197388
  value1   value2   value3 
  0.7200   0.0000 449.4002 
----------------------------------------------------------- 
dat$unique.identifier: 197392
value1 value2 value3 
    NA     NA     NA
```

where `dat` is the name of your data frame.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `plyr` package

```
set.seed(1618)
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1,1,2,3,3,3,4,4,4,5),
                  x = rnorm(10),
                  y = runif(10))

library(plyr)
ddply(dat, .(id), summarise, var1 = var(x), var2 = var(y))

  id       var1        var2
1  1 0.06147503 0.009907597
2  2         NA          NA
3  3 2.18725353 0.097501569
4  4 0.52691906 0.009814862
5  5         NA          NA
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer is quite similar to the Sven Hohenstein answer but perhaps is easy to understand.

Why not `subset` according to the `unique.identifier` and then the `var`, all with base functions:
First I read your data

```
help <- read.table(text="   unique.identifier zip.code household profession gender age value1   value2 value3 coupon
1               197386 47508827         4        low female  24  35.13    82.50   0.00      1
2               197386 47508827         4        low female  24  36.01    72.98   0.00      1
3               197386 47508827         4        low female  24  35.87    82.13   0.00      1
4               197386 47508827         4        low female  24  38.87    76.62   0.00      1
5               197386 47508827         4        low female  24  41.89     0.00   0.00      1
6               197388 17557326         2        low      m  38  26.81     0.00  29.98      1
7               197388 17557326         2        low      m  38  25.61     0.00   0.00      1
10              197392 22830028         2        low      m  33  25.66     0.00  19.99      1", header=TRUE)
```

Then the subset to get just the desired with the same `unique.identifier`, the subset can be change to whatever you want, :

```
help2 <- subset(help, unique.identifier=="197386")
unique.identifier zip.code household profession gender age value1 value2
1            197386 47508827         4        low female  24  35.13  82.50
2            197386 47508827         4        low female  24  36.01  72.98
3            197386 47508827         4        low female  24  35.87  82.13
4            197386 47508827         4        low female  24  38.87  76.62
5            197386 47508827         4        low female  24  41.89   0.00
```

And finally the variance, of just the desired columns (you could also set there the names :`sapply(help2[,c("value1", "value2", "value3")], FUN=var)`),

```
sapply(help2[,7:9], FUN=var)
    value1     value2     value3 
   7.90708 1250.04828    0.00000
```

Answer (score 0):

using package `dplyr`,

`group_by(id) %>% summarise(var1 = var(var1), var2=var(var2))` would do.